# vlcj - how to get the most granular current video time?

Tags: vlcj

Currently, I am using MediaPlayer's `getTime()` method to get current video time when my video is being played. I have a loop running, inside the loop, I call the `getTime()` method and then `Thread.sleep(100)`.

What I noticed it, `getTime()` returns an updated time about 3-4 times per second. Is that the most granular update I can get about current video time? I would like to get an updated time about every 0.1 second. Is that possible?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It simply isn't possible, what vlcj gives you is constrained by what the native LibVLC media_player_get_time API call returns.

Also, it's probably more usual to listen for media player "time changed" events than it is to poll for the current time.

Comment: `"time changed"` event returns the same "slowpoke" time

Answer (score 1):

The onDisplay() method for the Renderer class is called every frame, which you can use to manually track the frame you're on.

Comment: This is actually incorrect in all cases. Would not recommend.